# Alphabetically case insentive sort in activerecord when there are accents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here is one of my model that I am using

```
class WorkPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope -> { order(:label) }
end
```

Right now the sort will render something like

```
WorkPost.pluck(:label)
=> ["Chanteur", "Vétérinaire", "responsable du recrutement", "Économiste"]
```

However, I expect the alphabetical order to take into account "É" and to be case insensitive. However, I need to return something like :

```
WorkPost.pluck(:label)
=> ["Chanteur", "Économiste", "responsable du recrutement", "Vétérinaire"]
```

I expect this to be done at the ActiveRecord level in order to have good performances.

Comment: If it's going to be done on the active record level then it should be done at the database level. In which case it would be worth mentioning which database you are using and what, if any, storage options you have chosen.

Comment: Hello, I am using postegresql, encoding in unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve the case issue, we can use the solution from LHH https://stackoverflow.com/a/22376515/1839692.

However to solve the accent issue, we can use the PostgreSQL extension, [unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html) module.

To install it:

```
class AddUnaccentToPostgres < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    enable_extension "unaccent"
  end
end
```

And to sort the table with no accent (and no uppercase) :

```rb
default_scope order: 'lower(unaccent(label))'
```

Answer (score 3):

You could change the default scope to order by the lower case label:

```
default_scope order: 'lower(label)'
```

Or you could use upper case instead:

```
default_scope order: 'upper(label)'
```

hope this helps

Comment: That is indeed better it solves my case issue problem, but it doesn't solve my problem of dealing with accent.
I have => ["Chanteur", "responsable du recrutement", "Vétérinaire", "Économiste"]
Witch is closer but not exactly what I want.